# Locally hosted repository for GIT similarly to SVN local one?

Tags: git, svn, repository, local

A google search for [Locally hosted repository for GIT similarly to SVN local one?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Locally%20hosted%20repository%20for%20GIT%20similarly%20to%20SVN%20local%20one%3F&oq=Locally%20hosted%20repository%20for%20GIT%20similarly%20to%20SVN%20local%20one%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.275j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) give me nothing helpful so I ask our community here - is it possible to create a local repo using Git [similarly to what we can do with SVN local repo](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/142128/87964) i.e. no need for an SVN/Git server, we store it locally right on our PC's hard drive?

Answer (score 2):

Just run `git init` in any directory, and that directory is a Git repository.

Comment: I dit `git init` and `git commit` the new added files/folders - now I cannot `push` the changeset. May you add more details on how can we work with such a local Git repo @chepner?

Comment: In other words, may you show more instruction on how to make a `pull request` to such local repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a local Git repo, but you wouldn't "push" after that.

You would directly work in that local Git repo which will include all your history:

```
git init myrepo
cd myrepo
# copy/create files there
git add .
git commit -m "my files"
# work
git add .
git commit -m "my work"
...
```

If you want to push that local repo to a newly created empty GitHub repo for example, you would need:

- first to login to GitHub and create an empty repo
- secondly, to add that remote to your local repo

  ```
  git remote add origin https://<yourlogin>@github.com/<yourlogin>/<yourRepo>
  ```
- finally, you could push to it:

  ```
  git push -u origin master
  ```

Comment: I got it - so that means with Git we cannot clone/pull from a local URL e.g. `file:///C:/path/to/my/repo` as we can do with SVN, right @VonC?

Comment: @NamGVU you most certainly can: no need for file:/// url. You would be using the git local protocol (http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol): `git clone c:\path\to\repo myclone`. The difference is: you end up in 'myclone' folder with a *full* copy of the repo (with all its history), instead of SVN HEAD in a workspace.

Comment: Oh, I see - and yours has explained while I keep getting errors by giving `file:///` in the URL. Thank you VonC. Got accepted there then ^^

Comment: So sorry @VonC - I just failed to clone from Git local repo. May I ask for your sample git commands for such thing - from creating the repo to cloning it to another location. Thank you!

Comment: @NamGVU what command did you type, and what error message did you get?